# read pdf file with original contents

Tags: java, pdf, text-extraction, text-formatting

I want to read pdf file with original content like its font(its possible that some font size is small while some font size is big ) and paragraph and table if it is.

how its possible.

plz help.

Answer (score 0):

You want a library such as [jPod](http://opensource.intarsys.de/home/en/index.php?n=OpenSource.JPod), which can parse PDF documents back into the structure they were generated from. The PDF specification is seriously complex, but if you just want to scrape text and maybe a font size or two, that shouldn't be too hard to do.

Comment: Hi
is it possible read doc file with original contents....like paragraph and font size,font color and table???

Comment: Unless the PDF was created as structured content, this is not in the file - it needs to be guessed. I wrote a blog article explaining what is inside a PDF at http://pdf.jpedal.org/java-pdf-blog/bid/12670/PDF-text